# recovery from DataServiceRequestException using try catch

Tags: try-catch, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service and a wpf client consuming it.

I have surrounded each call to the dataservice in the client with try catch blocks. Here is an example where I create a product.

```
    try
        {
            Product product = Product.CreateProduct(productName, productNumber);

            context.AddToProduct(product);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DataServiceRequestException dataServiceRequestException)
        {
            Handle(dataServiceRequestException);
        }
```

This all works well - I get an exception for example when the product number already exists. My question is how do I recover in the client when such an exception has been thrown. In other words how do I implement the Handle()-method. If I for example just show a messagebox with the content of the error message, the next time I try to create a product the same error occurs. In other words how do I make the context forget that there was an error. I've been looking for a context.Clear() og context.Forget() but no such method seems to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to add a finally-clause, and reinitialize the context.